# Mathematica, calling functions from another notebook

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica

Is it possible to call functions from other notebooks in Mathematica, and if so how can I do it?

Answer (score 10):

Unless you specify otherwise, each notebook contributes to the `` Global` `` context. So, to call a function in notebook `a` from notebook `b`: first ensure that the definition is loaded into the context (i.e. select the cell with the definition and hit <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>enter</kbd>), and then the definition is available to notebook `b`, and any other notebooks you have open.

To prevent this behavior, you can change the [Notebook's Default Context](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/menuitem/NotebookDefaultContext.html) from the `Evaluation` menu. There are four options: `` Global` `` (the default), another specified context, unique to the notebook, unique to the cell group. For the cell group, each input cell takes the context of the nearest enclosing group, e.g. a Subsection, for instance, and those groupings have unique contexts.

Comment: Thank you! But what if I haven't got the other notebook opened, and just want to call a previous function which is saved in another notebook?

Comment: @John, not directly, no. You can create a [package](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/StandardExtraPackages.html) that is loaded upon demand, but it is still loaded. I'd recommend going the package route, myself.

Comment: That is a shame. I will look into packages! Thank you!

Comment: @John it is essentially the same in any language, the code has to be available for the system (or compiler) to use it.

Comment: @John, last thing, I swear! There's a new [mathematica.se] only site, if your interested.

Comment: One final question: Is it possible to overwrite predefined Mathematica functions?

Comment: @John system functions, or user-defined functions?

Comment: system functions. For example Fibonacci[] or EvenQ[]

Comment: @John Yes, using `Unprotect`, but I'd argue against it as care must be taken.

Comment: OK thank you, have a nice evening(or day depending on where you are:))